# Unable to copy Img src to hidden input value using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Below is a html/javascript code which i use to split a image into 2. From the below code u may see that the image is created dynamically by running my JS code and appended in

> `<div id="output"></div>`

The result would look like [(Click here to view debug code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2h9f.jpg) after the javascript is executed to "split" the image.

Now i would want to add the "img src" value (as shown in above debug code) into a hidden input type. I have coded the JS function "copySRC();" which will execute upon clicking the submit button. However during debugging of the JS script, the img src value did not copy over to the "hidden input type"'s value attribute.

I could not seem to find the issue.

(Note: I have tried the code in a separate test html/js code and it worked but now having the issue)

Please assist. Thanks All :)

Sniplet of JS Code

```
function copySRC()
{
    var img_left_data = document.getElementsByName("Image_Left").src;
    var img_right_data = document.getElementsByName("Image_Right").src;

    document.getElementsByName("img_left_D").value = img_left_data;
    document.getElementByName("img_right_D").value = img_right_data;
}
```

CSS

```
#output_container 
{
    display: none;
}

#output img 
{
    border: gray 1px solid;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

html

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<div id="output_container">
    <h2>Output</h2>
    <div id="output"></div>

    <input type="hidden" id="img_hidden_data" name="img_left_D" value="123"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="img_hidden_data" name="img_right_D" value="123"/>
    <input type="submit" value="send" onclick="copySRC();"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Simplify your code, too much redundancy

Comment: I simplified the code to more importance once. Please help if possible Thanks :)

Comment: does img_left_data get initialized at all? (use debugger to stop execution and inspect)

Comment: it does not store any value, it shows as undefined.

Comment: You have nothing called Image_Left so document.getElementsByName("Image_Left") will always be an empty collection

Comment: Hi, Thx for your help :). I would like to mention that in the question you may click and see "(Click here to view debug code)" and that there is a "Image_left". But it it is created dynamically by my javascript which appends the <img> tag into the <div> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try getting src it should return whole image path with domain name , the code looks good , you can try using getAttribute , it will return only what is mentioned in the src attribute .

```
<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley id="im" name="simg" face" width="42"  height="42" />
<input type="hidden" name="ih" />
<input type="button" value="copy" onclick="docpy()" />

<script type="text/javascript">
 function docpy()
  {
    var imgSrc = document.getElementsByName("simg");
    var hrc = document.getElementsByName("ih");
    hrc[0].value =   imgSrc[0].getAttribute("src");
    alert(hrc[0].value);

  }
```

Comment: Hi, Thx for your help. I would like to check if the above will still will work if the <img> tag is inside a <div> tag?

Answer (score 1):

[`getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) returns a collection. You want to do:

```
function copySRC()
{
    var img_left_data = document.getElementsByName("Image_Left")[0].src;
    var img_right_data = document.getElementsByName("Image_Right")[0].src;

    document.getElementsByName("img_left_D")[0].value = img_left_data;
    document.getElementsByName("img_right_D")[0].value = img_right_data;
}
```

Comment: And the last one should also be `getElementsByName`, not `getElementByName`.

Comment: @damo-s   Hi, thx for the reply. but i receiving an error "    var img_left_data = document.getElementsByName("Image_Left")[0].src; **img_left_data = undefined**    
                                          var img_right_data = document.getElementsByName("Image_Right")[0].src; **img_left_data = undefined**

    document.getElementsByName("img_left_D")[0].value = img_left_data;
    document.getElementsByName("img_right_D")[0].value = img_right_data;

Comment: @damo-s Not Sure why it shows as undefined when the variable should have been declared and value assigned directly. Thx for Your help :)